# Where can I find doc or description about % # @ address bar tricks?

Tags: firefox

If you open a tab in [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox), and you type `% pattern`, you will search in all the tabs the pattern.

But I know that there's another tricks with `#` and `@`, but it's difficult to search this on a search engine.

Anyone having doc link or explanations of these tricks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address bar of Firefox is called "Awesome Bar" and under that name you can find some information about it's features.
Little excerpt from [Firefox's Support Site](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-search-firefox-bookmarks-history-tabs):

> ```
> Add ^ to search for matches in your browsing history.
> Add * to search for matches in your bookmarks.
> Add + to search for matches in pages you've tagged.
> Add % to search for matches in your currently open tabs.
> Add ~ to search for matches in pages you've typed.
> Add # to search for matches in page titles.
> Add @ to search for matches in web addresses (URLs).
> Add $ to search for matches in suggestions.
> ```